# Rails is not compiling the css files in application.scss?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am new in ruby on rails and I am trying hard from last 3 hours to include my css files in the vendor/stylesheet/ directory in application.scss but it is not working.

css files path is

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

This is my code Application.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require custom
 *= require pgwmodal.min
 */
```

This is the code of application.html

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload',debug: true  %>
```

My project mode is development.

I have to restart the server and cleared browser cache but still no luck.

Comment: What you mean for .scss version. It is the standard way which I am following.Your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check you console to see if your assets are loading from anywhere. Sometimes you will need to make it `.css.scss` instead of just `.scss`. You can usually just leave it as `.css`. This all depends on your compiler and rails version. Have you tried forgoing manually putting them in for favor of `require_tree .` ?

Your custom `.css` would need to be in the stylesheets folder. If you are trying to load from the vendor's folder you would use a different approach.

Comment: css file path is vendor/assets/stylesheets/

Comment: Your original question has Application.scss, if that's the case change it to application.scss. It seems like you are building from the group up? Maybe remove turbolinks if you are using it. Anything in console?